# Что почитать про табличные методы?

Tags: алгоритм, .net

Встретил в книге упоминание про табличные методы, но краткое. Например, таблицы прямого доступа позволяют поулчать значение функции из таблицы с заранее вычисленными значениями. Где почитать подробнее?

Comment: Думаю, там нечего читать. Ну, закешировали вы значения функции, вот и вся идея

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обратитесь к главе 18 книги ["Совершенный код"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5508646/) Стива Макконнелла. Там все подробно описано.

---

Если вкратце, то табличные методы являются заменой выражениям `if` и `case`. В большинстве случаев их можно заменить.

Различаются следующие способы поиска:

- прямой доступ (по индексу)
- индексированный доступ (по ключу)
- ступенчатый доступ (по верхней границе для диапазонов данных)

Хранить в таблице можно как данные, так и действия, которые нужно произвести (в терминах .NET это `Action` или `Func`).

Структуры данных (т.е. сами "таблицы"), применяемые в табличных методах:

- массивы (для прямого и ступенчатого доступа)
- хэш-таблицы (для индексированного доступа, `Dictionary<K, V>` в терминах .NET)

Comment: а о каких таблицах идет речь?

Comment: @jokelocker обновил ответ.